# Is Encoding.GetBytes(String) implemented in ASCIIEncoding class?

Tags: c#

This is what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `ASCIIEncoding` says for `GetBytes(String)`:

> When overridden in a derived class, encodes all the characters in the
>   specified string into a sequence of bytes. (Inherited from Encoding.)

So does that means that `GetBytes(String)` does not have an implementation in `ASCIIEncoding`? Isn't the point of creating a virtual method in the base class (`Encoding`) is to override it in the derived classes (`ASCIIEncoding`, `UnicodeEncoding`, `UTF8Encoding`, etc.)?

---

***Edit:*** I have only found the implementation for the following functions in the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/asciiencoding.cs) for `ASCIIEncoding`: `GetBytes(String, Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32)`, `GetBytes(Char[], Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32)`, and `GetBytes(Char*, Int32, Byte*, Int32)`.

Comment: It is a copy/paste bug, a common mishap in MSDN articles.  It came from the article for the Encoding class.

Comment: @Hans Passant What is the copy/paste bug? Now that I think about it, I don't think that there is anything wrong with the documentation, I mean `ASCIIEncoding` simply does not override `GetBytes(String)`, and so the virtual method is inherited as is into `ASCIIEncoding`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the documentation.

If you view the [methods list for the ASCIIEncoding type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.ASCIIEncoding_methods(v=vs.110).aspx), the link for the `GetBytes(String)` function takes you to the documentation for the base/abstract `Encoding.GetBytes(String)` method, rather than the `ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(String)` method. It appears to be an error in the link. It may be that the base `Encoding.GetBytes(String)` method already does the right things in the case of the ASCII character set, but if so it's strange that other methods in the `ASCIIEncoding` class documentation do link to implementations directly on that type, and that the documentation for the Encoding method doesn't indicate this.

Comment: I think you have an extra 'not' in the second sentence.

Comment: @RufusL Fixed, and also added a new twist.

Comment: The link is not wrong, just the description.  ASCIIEncoding doesn't override GetString(byte[]).

Comment: @HansPassant I covered that scenario near the of the answer. If that's the case, then the documentation for Encoding.GetString() needs clarification, and it's still a documentation issue.

Comment: Some `GetBytes()` functions takes you to `Encoding.GetBytes()` because they are not overridden in `ASCIIEncoding`, while others takes you to `ASCIIEncoding` because they are overridden. I have looked at the source code for `ASCIIEncoding` and there are only 3 out of 6 `GetBytes()` functions that are overridden. I don't think that there is anything wrong with the documentation. I think that the answer to my question is simply: `GetBytes(String)` is not overridden in `ASCIIEncoding`.

Comment: When you call `GetBytes(String)` the `Encoding` class method will be executed, which will call `GetBytes(String, Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32)` which is a virtual method, which causes the derived class (for example: `ASCIIEncoding`) method to be executed). So the work is ultimately done in `ASCIIEncoding` and not in `Encoding`.